# nfs4 rpc.idmapd not working on one machine

Tags: nfs, nfs4

I have an nfs4 server, with fsid=0 exported with

```
no_subtree_check,no_all_squash,no_root_squash
```

I have various clients working fine with this, a mixture of debian and arch, mounting with nfs4 and uids and gids, userids and groups, are reported correctly with files.

However, one gentoo box does map the ids correctly.  The userids are present on both sides, even the uids are the same, and the Domain is correctly set in /etc/idmapd.conf and is running.

All files are presented with the `4294967294:4294967294` user/group, despite having userids and uids, groups and gids that match the client.

If I run idmapd in the foreground, with extra verbosity, I see that it is getting the domain right:

```
sudo rpc.idmapd -vvvvvvvv -f
rpc.idmapd: libnfsidmap: using domain: hum

rpc.idmapd: libnfsidmap: loaded plugin libnfsidmap_nsswitch.so for method nsswitch

rpc.idmapd: Expiration time is 600 seconds.
rpc.idmapd: Opened /proc/net/rpc/nfs4.nametoid/channel
rpc.idmapd: Opened /proc/net/rpc/nfs4.idtoname/channel
rpc.idmapd: New client: 16
rpc.idmapd: New client: 17
[warn] event_del: event has no event_base set.
rpc.idmapd: Stale client: 17
rpc.idmapd:     -> closed /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs//nfs/clnt17/idmap
[warn] event_del: event has no event_base set.
rpc.idmapd: Stale client: 16
rpc.idmapd:     -> closed /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs//nfs/clnt16/idmap
rpc.idmapd: New client: 18
rpc.idmapd: New client: 19
rpc.idmapd: New client: 1a
```

All appears to be working correctly.  The kernel has the correct settings enabled:

```
CONFIG_FSNOTIFY=y
CONFIG_DNOTIFY=y
CONFIG_INOTIFY_USER=y
CONFIG_FANOTIFY=y
CONFIG_NFS_FS=m
CONFIG_NFS_V3=y
# CONFIG_NFS_V3_ACL is not set
CONFIG_NFS_V4=y
CONFIG_NFS_V4_1=y
CONFIG_PNFS_FILE_LAYOUT=m
# CONFIG_NFS_USE_LEGACY_DNS is not set
CONFIG_NFS_USE_KERNEL_DNS=y
CONFIG_NFS_USE_NEW_IDMAPPER=y
CONFIG_NFSD=m
CONFIG_NFSD_DEPRECATED=y
CONFIG_NFSD_V3=y
# CONFIG_NFSD_V3_ACL is not set
CONFIG_NFSD_V4=y
CONFIG_NFS_COMMON=y
```

The gentoo client is running 2.6.39 x86 and the server is running 2.6.32 x64

Any ideas what else might be missing?